# import tensorflow_addons as tfa on conda

Tags: python, tensorflow

i cannot install `tensorflow_addons` on python on VS code on my anaconda environemnt
I have tried using different variations of pip install / conda install but none seem to work for me, and i am getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_addons'
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just a typo. It is not `tensorflow_addons` but `tensorflow-addons`. So:

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```